# NSTimer stops my image from moving

Tags: ios, objective-c, nstimer

When I hold down on a button my image will move to a direction.

The game objective is that they are going to move image to hit another image, and to do that I'm using an `NSTimer`.

Then they also have another `NSTimer` because they only have 15 seconds on them to hit the other image. If they don't the game will [self gameover] but, the `NSTimer` that counts the 15 seconds is started and I move the image the image moves a bit and then it goes back to center again.

When I delete the countdown timer, the image does not go back to center after I stop pressing the button but it stops on its current position.

And that's what I want it to do while I'm using the countdown timer as well.

Code:

```
-(void)goLeft 
{ 
      ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x -5, ball.center.y); 
} 

-(IBAction)left 
{ 
      goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
      if (goLeft == nil) goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 
} 

-(IBAction)stopLeft 
{ 
      [goLeft invalidate]; 
      goLeft = nil; 
}

//And heres the timer :

-(IBAction)doCountdown: (id)sender;{




    if (countdownTimer)
        return;


    remainingTicks = 25;
    [self updateLabel];

    countdownTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 target: self selector: @selector(handleTimerTick) userInfo: nil repeats: YES];


}

-(void)handleTimerTick
{
    remainingTicks--;
    [self updateLabel];

    if (remainingTicks <= 0) {
        [countdownTimer invalidate];
        countdownTimer = nil;
    }
}


-(void)updateLabel
{
    theLabel.text = [[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedInt: remainingTicks] stringValue];
}
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend against using `NSTimer` for timing animations. If you'd like, I could answer any questions about `SpriteKit` which is a much better (and easier) alternative for animating actions.

Comment: @JaredH agreed. At the very least, if OP insists on using `UIKit`, he should be using a `CADisplayLink` to sync his updates with the run loop, or use Core Animation to handle the animations.

Comment: @JaredH If you can move the image right, left, up, and down with holding down a button and then it stops with letting go, yes show me:) Also, can i use a timer then to countdown how much time they have left to finish the mission? Thanks for answear :D

Comment: @bbum Ok let me show you an example, like when i move it left

Comment: @JaredH and if its in objective c im fine :) But i really dont like swift

Comment: @bbum -(void)goLeft { ball.center = CGPointMake(ball.center.x -5, ball.center.y);          }                                                                                                                                 -(IBAction)left { goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; if (goLeft == nil) { goLeft = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.05 target:self selector:@selector(goLeft) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; }

-(IBAction)stopLeft { [goLeft invalidate]; goLeft = nil;
    
}

Comment: This works fine, i can move the image to the left with this code and when i let go of the button, the image stops where i stopped it. But then i add the nstimer, and then every it messes up everything. When i let go of the button then, the image will just go back to center, where the game started:(

Comment: What benefit do you think there is to calling `+scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:...` a second time if the original call failed?

Comment: @Tommy I said it does work with the image moving but when i use it the second time on a countdown, it doesnt work.

Comment: None of your code shows adjusting the ball's center back to the middle.  So, either you aren't posting all the relevant code or your second timer is causing the view to be re-initialized somehow.   As others have said, `NSTimer` really isn't the right way to do this.  I'd have a look here as I bet there are several tutorials that are relevant.  http://www.raywenderlich.com/category/ios

Comment: @bbum Is there any other ways making the ball move with a touch down action and stop with a touch up? :)